# How to properly use map() in a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary

Im pretty nub at react and JS, so, this is probably a stupid question, but, when I try to use the .map() in a array like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  productsArray = [
    'Cajo T-shirt',
    'Geometric Skull',
    'Bavaria 350 mL',
    'Inflatable Alien',
    'R2D2 RC Car',
  ];
renderCategories(arrayDeProdutos) {
    return arrayDeProdutos.map((index) => <Text key={index}></Text>);
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderCategories()}
        </View>
    );
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

I got the following error message: "arrayDeProdutos.map is not a object". I tryed to read the map documentation, but it did'n answered my question.

Comment: `{this.renderCategories(this.productsArray)}`

Comment: in `{this.renderCategories()}` you need to pass argument. Change to `{this.renderCategories(this.productsArray)}`

Answer (score 1):

`renderCategories` methods expects a parameter but you pass none as can be seen here:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    {this.renderCategories()}
</View>
```

Here is what you need to do isntead.

```
renderCategories(arrayDeProdutos) {
    return arrayDeProdutos.map((index) => <Text key={index}></Text>);
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderCategories(this.productsArray)}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: oh, yeah, I forgot to pass the parameter... I'll Try it out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your render function would look like the following :

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.productsArray.map((prod, index) => <Text key={index}>{prod}</Text>)}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Be careful as `map` will return the index of your item as the second parameter and not the first one.

By putting your `map` in the render function there is no need for `renderCategories` to exist.

I would also recommend putting this array in your state if it can change at runtime. This will allow your app to re-render your text after any change is made to it.

Another thing, anything declared in a class is accessible via `this.` in this same class, no need to pass any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass argument to `renderCategories()`. So change

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.renderCategories()}
        </View>
    );
}
```

to

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            // pass "this.productsArray" as an argument
            {this.renderCategories(this.productsArray)}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the other answers are right, but I do not agree with using an index in this case. Also, I think in a real situation you will get your data from backend and most likely you will have an `id`. So you can use your `id` as an `index`. ( I prefer arrow functions )

```
const productsArray = [
  "Cajo T-shirt",
  "Geometric Skull",
  "Bavaria 350 mL",
  "Inflatable Alien",
  "R2D2 RC Car"
];

export default class App extends React.Component {
  //using arrow function

  renderCategories = products => products.map(product => <Text key={product}>{product}</Text>);

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>{this.renderCategories(productsArray)}</div>
    );
  }
}
```